# Identifying the Push Notification Message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

In my project I want to show the events and offers through push notification, but the problem is, I'm able to show the events or offers, not both. Is there any way to identify the message of Push notification. Here's the code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSString *message = nil;
    id alert = [userInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];

    if ([alert isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        message = alert;
    } else if ([alert isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        message = [alert objectForKey:@"body"];
    }
    if (alert) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                            message:@"AThe message." delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"button 1"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"button", nil];
        [alertView show];
    }

    NSString *contentsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"contTag"];
    NSLog(@"Received contents info : %@", contentsInfo);

    NSString *nibName = [AppDelegate fetchNibWithViewControllerName:@"EventsViewController"];

    EventsViewController *evc = [[EventsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];

    evc.newEvent = YES;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:evc animated:YES];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"badgecount"] intValue];
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "dentify the message of Push notification"? You can differentiate content by adding another field in payload e.g. "type":"event" OR "type":"offer" OR you can also pare the message of alert.

Comment: thanks for the quick response... will u gimme the actual code for that like, in the above code am getting only events. If i got msge like "NEW OFFER".how can i get the offersViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alert` is always an `NSDictionary` with two keys: body and show-view. The value of the former is the alert message and the latter is a `Boolean` (`false` or `true`). If `false`, the alert’s View button is not shown. The default is to show the View button which, if the user taps it, launches the application.

check the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

To identify type of the message you can provide additional fields, as described [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/66521/how-to-get-access-to-custom-field-in-apple-push-notification)

Example:

```
{
   "aps":{
      "badge":1,
      "alert":"This is my special message!",
      "mycustomvar1":"123456",
      "mycustomvar2":"some text",
      "myspecialtext":"This is the best!",
      "url":"http://www.mywebsite.com"
   }
}
```

Comment: can u explain me a bit of it like, am getting "THIS IS MY NEW EVENT" message from the APNS, so how can i do identify that msge.....help me out bro

Comment: there are at least two ways:
1) message from APNS should include custom field indicating type of message - offer or event
2) if case 1 is not possible you can parse message text, and search for type-specific strings like "offer" or "event"

Comment: The alert isn't always a NSDictionary I got caught out by this, sometimes it can be a string ;)